# twisted.web.client - getPage() fails to give response if the http webserver its calling doesn't respond with HTTP "Connection: close"

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, twisted

I make a `getPage()` call to a web server which doesn't respond with `Connection: close` in HTTP header. I am getting `Connection was closed cleanly` failure without the response. The webserver has send the response but getPage() doesn't show it

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.]
```

Comment: consider using ``treq`` module. I think it handles some of the subtleties of ``getPage()``.  And it's very similar to ``requests``.

Comment: @notoriousThanks for the recommendation on `treq` ! This kinda works. Also I see this is Based on Agent requests. We did a similar thing but it needed SSL support. Seems like it already has SSL support. Thanks !